# Error in AIX Server while running loadjava: not found

Tags: java, oracle

I'm trying to start `loadjava` on AIX Server and I get a Java notfound error.

> /app/oracle/...../loadjava[72]: /app/oracle11.../bin/java: not found

The second path does not exist, I've looked into `.profile` and `env`, looks ok.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you moved things around since installing? `loadjava` is a shell script, one of the first things it does is define JAVA_HOME (so your profile/env settings won't matter much). From the edited output you showed it looks like it was created with a path that no longer exists?

Comment: You might want to install some jdk/jre version (e.g. the newest available version of IBM java8/64bit), and edit this 'loadjava' script so that it start the java executable.

Comment: If you have access to My Oracle Support, look at Doc ID 1184794.1 - which seems to suggest it's acceptable to just edit the `loadjava` script to make it point to the correct Java home. It isn't obvious why ti might be wrong.